# How to count elements in a row of a two-dimensional array?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I know that a question similar to this has been asked before, but I want to ask this, which is slightly different:

Here is example: `counts[[0,10,4,2], [0,0,0,0,5,7]]`

If I wanted to count the number of a specific element, lets say 0 in a two dimensional array for one part of the array like `counts[0]`, how would we do so? Trying to do things for project Euler q3. So like the example output here should be 1, if we did it for `counts[1]` which should give: 4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item) Writing "Not a duplicate" in the title does not make your question so. You still want to count the number of zeros in a one-dimensional list. The only difference now is that your list is accessed as `counts[0]` instead of at `mylist`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just directly access the "part" of the list using its index like `counts[0]` and then call the python built-in list function `count` to count the appearances of the desired value:

```
counts = [[0, 10, 4, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7]]

print(counts[0].count(0))
print(counts[1].count(0))

# Output
1
4
```